# How to Add Custom field All payment method in magento2 by progmatically?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Ex-See field Select Country in bydefault..
i will add new field customer group in all payment method.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a system.xml file for your module.

**[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="400" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="checkmo" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="customer_group" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Customer Group</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Source\Group</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: thnx. but if i added new payment module its not set automatically so i need to set by progmatically..how it possible?@Sohel

Comment: you just create a module for adding this system config only

Comment: but not possible to create observer throw set field in all payment method???

Comment: programmatically means?

Comment: using some event or rewrite magento core files

Answer (score 0):

path - /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.test" template="Magento_Catalog::customvideo.phtml" after="-" />
            </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```